# I am trying to make a height calculator based on genetics. But javascript doesn't return the expected answer

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm a very new guy to javascript. Tryin' to figure it out since I've learnt Java though. 
Hope you guys helped me out

This is my forms :

```
<form>
    Male <input type="radio" id="male" name="selects"/>
    Female <input type="radio" id="female" name="selects"/><br/>
    Mom's height <input type="text" id="moms"/>
    Dad's height <input type="text" id="dads"/>
    <input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('dads').value, document.getElementById('moms').value);"/>
</form>
```

This is my Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate (d, m) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById('male').checked) 
        {
            var result = (d+m+13)/2;
            document.write(result);
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById('female').checked) 
        {
            var result = (d+m-13)/2;
            document.write(result);
        } 
        else
        {
            alert("Choose a gender!");
        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.  Instead, use the DOM to set the text of a result element.

Comment: You should probably include information like, a. what it's doing, and b. what you're expecting it to be doing that's different from a...

Comment: **Awesome** guys! Detailed answer and also some good practices. **Thx** in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input values are strings, you need to parse them to integer (using `parseInt()`) before doing numeric operations.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/4aV9g/)

Try the below code:

```
function calculate (d, m) 
{
    if (document.getElementById('male').checked) 
    {
        var result = (parseInt(d,10)+parseInt(m,10)+13)/2;
        document.write(result);
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById('female').checked) 
    {
        var result = (parseInt(d,10)+parseInt(m,10)-13)/2;
        document.write(result);
    } 
    else
    {
        alert("Choose a gender!");
    }

}
```

**Note:** As already pointed out by others, it is not good practice to use `document.write` because they repaint the whole screen. Instead you can have a output div and assign the result to its `innerHTML` like below.

`document.getElementById('output_div').innerHTML = result;`

Comment: It's good practice to define the base argument for `parseInt`, usually it's base 10 (for the decimal system), thus make `parseInt(x, 10)` with x being the number to be parsed.
This is done because if some strange numbers is passed into parseInt, it can assume non-decimal systems. I.e. `parseInt('0x10') == 16`

Comment: Wow, never thought that somebody's going to answer that fast and with a very detailed answer! You guys rock! Thx in advance.

Comment: Yay **It works** !! The `document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML` also works great!